# solving logarithmic equation for integral calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Doing this as part of a integral calculus folio im working on trying to equate areas above and under the $x$-axis as bounded by a logarithmic function. Ran into this equation i couldnt seem to solve:
$$
x\ln\left(\,x + 1\,\right) - 2x + \ln\left(\,x + 1\,\right) = 0.
$$
Trying to solve for $x$. i have tried factoring, letting
$\ln\left(\,x + 1\,\right)$ = $u$ but cant seem to solve for $x$.

Comment: What do you think about my second answer ? Funny, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

your equation can be written in the form
$$(x+1)\ln(x+1)-2x=0$$ 
we see that $$x=0$$ is one solution.The second real solution can be obtained by a numerical method or the LambertW function. It is $$x\approx 3.92155363456750509245676231175$$
a numerical method is for example the Newton-Raphson method, you can google for it

Comment: what is the lambertW function? will applying it work for other functions of similar form? (lets say $xln(x+2) -4x+ln(x+2) = 0$?

Comment: see this here for your own studies http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: @lohboys. Any equation which can write $a+bx+c\log(d+ex)=0$ shows solutions in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: thank you, much appreciated

Comment: @lohboys. If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods will do the job.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i havent learned the mathematics behind either the lambert function or numerical methods. im still in high school. as for my folio, i might try another function type.

Comment: @lohboys. Don't worry ! It is very easy to understand Newton method for solving equations. I am sure than you can learn that by yourself quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the solution in terms of Lambert function, consider $$f(x)=(x+1) \log (x+1)-2 x$$ $$f'(x)=\log (x+1)-1$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$$ So, the first derivative cancels for $x_*=e-1$. Now $$x=x_*\implies f(x_*)=2-e <0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad  f''(x_*)=\frac 1e >0$$ So, this point is a minimum and, beside the trivial $x=0$, there is another root $x >e-1$.

Let us be lazy and expand the function as a Taylor series around $x=e-1$. You would get $$f(x)=(2-e)+\frac{(x-e+1)^2}{2 e}+O\left((x-e+1)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the approximation gives an estimate $$x=e-1+\sqrt{2e(e-2)}\approx 3.69439$$ which is not too bad for a guess.

For sure, you can use Newton method, say, starting with $x_0=e$. The iterations  given by $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n-1}{\log (x_n+1)-1}-1$$ will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.71828 \\
 1 & 4.48513 \\
 2 & 3.96428 \\
 3 & 3.92186 \\
 4 & 3.92155
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: wow i might have to give this a go! would you think using this method will allow for a conjecture to be proven? im starting with the function $ln (x+1) - n$ where $n>0$ and equating area under and above the x-axis as bounded by the function.

Comment: @lohboys. OK, let us do it together as a game. You write the equation you want to solve and I try to find the best approximation I could in order to support your conjecture. Let us go !

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, as you suggested in comments, let us search the value of $x$ which makes $$\int_0^x\left(\log(1+t)-n\right)\,dt=0$$ So, we have to find the zero of function $$f(x)=(x+1) \log (x+1)-(n+1) x$$ $$f'(x)=\log (x+1)-n=0\implies x_*=e^n-1$$ Expanding the function as a Taylor series around $x_*$ we have, as an approximation $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-n} \left(-e^n+x+1\right)^2-e^n+n+1$$ and then a first **under**estimate $$x_1=e^n-1+\sqrt 2 \sqrt{e^{2n}-(n+1)e^n}$$ At this point, we can perform one iteration of Newton method and get an **over**estimate $$x_2=\frac{e^n-1+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e^{2 n}-e^n (n+1)}-\log \left(e^n+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e^{2 n}-e^n
   (n+1)}\right)}{\log \left(e^n+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e^{2 n}-e^n (n+1)}\right)-n}$$  We could go beyond using Lambert function since the exact solution is given by $$x=-1-\frac{(n+1)}{W\left(-e^{-(n+1)} (n+1)\right)}$$ and use the fact that the argument of the Lambert function is small and so use, around $y=0$ the expansion $$W(y)=y-y^2+\frac{3 y^3}{2}+O\left(y^4\right)\implies \frac 1 {W(y)}=1+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{2}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which gives as another approximation $$x_3=e^{n+1}-(n+2)-\frac 12(n+1)^2e^{-(n+1)}$$ We could even do better using Padé approximants $$W(y)=\frac{y+\frac{4 }{3}y^2}{1+\frac{7 }{3}y+\frac{5 }{6}y^2}$$ to get another estimate $$x_4=e^{n+1}-(n+2)-\frac{3 (n+1)^2}{6 e^{n+1}-8 (n+1)}$$

Checking for a few values of $n$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 n & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4&\text{exact} \\
 1 & 3.69439 & 3.93146 & 4.11839 &3.96554 &3.92155 \\
 2 & 14.4427 & 15.8798 & 15.8615 &15.8058 &15.8010 \\
 3 & 44.5055 & 49.7506 & 49.4516 &49.4358 &49.4353 \\
 4 & 127.191 & 143.333 & 142.329 &142.325 &142.325 \\
 5 & 353.015 & 399.321 & 396.384 &396.383 &396.383 \\
 6 & 967.992 & 1096.84 & 1088.61 & 1088.61&1088.61 \\
 7 & 2640.84 & 2994.62 & 2971.95 & 2971.95&2971.95 \\
 8 & 7189.3 & 8155.04 & 8093.08 & 8093.08 &8093.08 \\
 9 & 19554.5 & 22184.3 & 22015.5 &22015.5 &22015.5 \\
 10 & 53167.8 & 60321.5 & 59862.1 &59862.1 &59862.1
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be quite good (I hope and wish !).

**Update**

I forgot to consider the case where $n$ could be small.

Using Taylor series, we would find
$$x=2 n+\frac{4 n^2}{3}+\frac{4 n^3}{9}+\frac{16 n^4}{135}+\frac{8
   n^5}{405}+O\left(n^6\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just using plain ol' Lambert W function:

Let $e^{y+2}=x+1$, then: 
$$(y+2)\cdot e^{y+2} = 2(e^{y+2}-1)\Longrightarrow\\
ye^{y+2}=-2\Longrightarrow\\
ye^y=-2e^{-2}\Longrightarrow\\
y=W(-2e^{-2})\Longrightarrow\\
e^y=\frac{-2e^{-2}}{W(-2e^{-2})}\Longrightarrow\\
e^{y+2}-1=e^{2}\frac{-2e^{-2}}{W(-2e^{-2})}-1\Longrightarrow\\
x=\frac{-2}{W(-2e^{-2})}-1\Longrightarrow\\
x\approx \frac{-2}{-.4063}-1\approx 3.922
$$